# How to get a reference of a ListView item to its datatemplates ViewModel which is created as static resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a view (lets call it 'mainview') which holds a `ListView` that is bound to a `Observablecollection` in the view's viewmodel.

The `ListView` defines usercontrol as datatemplate as follows:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              SelectionMode="Single">

...

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

...

                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <local:MyUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>

...

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The `UserControl` gets its own ViewModel as static resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <vm:UserControlViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource vm}">

...

</Grid>
```

My goal now to get a reference of either of the `ObservableCollection` bound to the 'mainview's `ListView` or one of it's items to the ViewModel of the UserControl without violating MVVM. It is also important not to have a copy, but only a reference.

My initial guess was to give it to the constructor of the `UserControl`'s ViewModel as argument, however I don't think this is possible from XAML...

Comment: A UserControl should never have its own view model in the first place. Just remove it and thus get the current item by the inherited DataContext.

Comment: Taking a closer look, you don't actually seem to set the UserControl's DataContext, but just that of a Grid in its XAML. Hence the UserControl's DataContext should already hold the associated item from the source collection when used in the ItemTemplate of a ListView.

Comment: As a note, unless you set the ListView's View property (e.g. to a GridView) you may as well use the more simple base class ListBox.

Comment: Thx, for the fast answer. I'm curious why UserControls shouldn't have their own ViewModels? What if I use them to create complete views within  the mainwindow that the user can switch between? I don't believe you should have all the databinding in one main viewmodel in that case, right?

Comment: I don't mean a UserControl shouldn't directly bind to a known set of properties inside its XAML. However, the source object of these Bindings should always be the inherited DataContext, no hidden private view model instance that is disconnected from the view model structure of your application.

Comment: Ok, understood. I'll get rid of the extra ViewModel. Thanks!